# Laptop specifications for implementation of blockchain

Tags: graphics, blockchain, implementation, specifications, processor

I have a question that I need to implement blockchain for tamper proof record so what laptop specifications would be required to implement blockchain?

Answer (score 0):

If u can run python or js u can make it so some dual-core laptop and u can also work on Linux without a GUI so old Pentium 3 will also work :D